# How to create a String of an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

I'm trying to create a String of an array {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} but I can't seem to get the right answer when I run it.

```
int [] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
String s = " ";

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  s = (arr[i] + ", ");
}

System.out.println(s);
```

The answer I get is 7 when I was actually hopping to get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

Can someone please explain to me why this code below gives me the correct answer but when I use a string it doesn't and how I should correct my code above.

```
int [] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
}
```

Comment: How about `Arrays.toString()`?

Comment: just replace `=`  with `+=`

Comment: In addition to the technical debugging of your code, when you're constructing a string like that in a loop, use a `StringBuilder` instead. Java `String` objects are immutable, and it's expensive to create and discard lots of intermediate copies; `StringBuilder` lets you add all the characters you need and then turn it into a `String`.

Comment: Per the close reasons, voting to close as a typo

Comment: @Everv0id that works too thanks but since I'm new to programming I'm trying to stay away from built in codes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reinitializing `s` at every iteration `s = arr[i] + " "` so when the loop is done `s` will be the last value in the array.

To add all the values to `s` you have to use `+=` instead of `=`

For example `s += String.valueOf(arr[i]) + " "`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't realized that strings worked that way.

Comment: @stargazer: To be perfectly correct, it aint Strings that works that way. It is the assignment operator '=' that works that way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *append* to your string. That is, you need to add another number on the end (using `+=`) instead of just re-assigning the string for each number (using `=`).

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
    s += arr[i] + " ";
}
```

Or more concisely:

```
for (int n : arr) {
    s += n + " ";
}
```

Or, if you don't want to get told off by people worried about performance, use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int n : arr) {
    s.append(n).append(' ');
}
String s = sb.toString();
```

Or just use [`Arrays.toString(arr)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) to do the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  s += (arr[i] + " ");   <<---- you we're missing the '+' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite your String, if you use `s = (arr[i] + " ");`.

Better use `s += (arr[i] + " ");` or `s = s.concat(arr[i] + " ");`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the first code is object  s is override on each iteration of for loop...that's why it is printing the last overrided value which is 7
To print all the values you can use 
s = s+(arr[i] + ", ");

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value to be printed out each time you get it from the array, you should put `System.out.println(s);` **inside** of your `for` loop, instead of after the `for` loop. If you are looking to print it all in one line, then you should use `s.concat(arr[i] + ", ");`. This will add the value from the array to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, for what you're looking for, just change `s = (arr[i] + ", ");` to `s = s.concat(arr[i] + ", ");`. That will give you a list, printed out. To make it look nicer, you could then take a character count of the string and use a substring to remove the last comma.

I hope this helps.